# Linked lists using nested classes?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the class `Agency` which has a private nested class `Node` that should be used to build a linked list of `Client` objects.

In order to add a node I need to use an overloaded `+=` operator that receives a `Client` object.
When I want to add the first object: the function calls the `setHead` member of the `Node` class.

But once I try to modify the data members of `head`: `data` to point to the received `Client` object and `next` to `NULL` a run-time error occurs.

I can't figure out whats wrong, the `Client` object is passed as it should be (I checked it) - I think that I'm missing something in the declaration of `setHead`'s arguments.

would be thankful for any advice. 
btw, I have to use the existing private members as they are and `setHead` method must receive a pointer to `Client`.

Agency.h

```
class Agency
{
    public:
        Agency(); //ctor
        Agency& operator+=(const Client&); //overloaded += operator
        ~Agency(); //dtor
    private:
        class Node //node as nested class
        {
            public:
            Node(); //ctor
            void setHead(Client*&); //set head node
            private:
            Client* data; //points to Client
            Node* next; //points to next node on the list
        };

        Node *head; //points to head node of database
};
```

Agency.cpp relevant methods

```
void Agency::Node::setHead(Client*& temp)
{
    data = temp;
    next = NULL;
}
Agency& Agency::operator+=(const Client& client_add)
{   
    Client* temp = new Client (client_add); //new client object is created using clients copy ctor
    if (!head) //if the head node is NULL
    {
        head->setHead(temp); //assign head node to point to the new client object 
    }
        return *this;
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the reply, I have yet another question:

I want to have a method of `Node` that will return a pointer to `Node`, here is the declaration:

```
    `Node* nextNode(Node*);`
```

Function:

```
    `Node* MatchmakingAgency::Node::nextNode(Node* start)`
```

Causes compilation error: `'Node' does not name a type`

How can I properly declare such a method?

Comment: Why not use `std::list`?

Comment: Can't - those are the rules of the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
if (!head) //in the head node is empty
    {
        head->setHead(temp);
```

`head` is not "empty". It's a null pointer. And then you dereference the null pointer which results in undefined behaviour.

Perhaps you meant to have this:

```
head = new Node();
```

before `setHead`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.
I'm actually ashamed that it was the problem.